# Syntax error when importing pytube on Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, chromebook, pytube

I am trying to use pytube on Ubuntu, but i get a syntax error when I try to use create a YouTube object

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/austin/Desktop/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pytube
  File "/home/austin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytube/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pytube.streams import Stream
  File "/home/austin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytube/streams.py", line 61
    self.is_otf: bool = stream["is_otf"]
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Please mention your Python version and include your code if possible.

Comment: @tdelaney It is evident from the traceback that the Python version is 3.5.

Comment: `pytube` only supports Python 3.6 and later, according to its documentation https://pytube.io/en/latest/ . That typing syntax did not exist in 3.5.

Comment: @ThisIsMatin The traceback indicates that the error occurs at the `import` statement in line 1 of OP's program. More code wouldn't provide any more helpful information.

Comment: Please also read their descriptions before applying tags and, as a new user here, take the tour and read ask.